# overwrite /dev/null with file

Tags: linux

On Debian stable, python 2.6.4

I have a script that overwrites /dev/null.

Any idea as to what could be happening?

The only thing I have is a typical cron job that redirects output to /dev/null, but that should not cause that, right?

Comment: There's no way that would be happening unless your script was running as root, and even then it's non-trivial.

Comment: Overwrites? /dev/null is an infinite sink of data.

Comment: I think this would be better tagged `linux` instead of `python` and `debian`.

Comment: Belongs to serverfault

Comment: Actually superuser, I think, since this is advanced usage of linux, nothing particularly server-ish.

Comment: If you could share the script or at least the offending lines with us, we can most likely tell you immediately what's going on.

Comment: Well, I don't know what causes it. That's the problem.

Comment: @Christpoher Mahan: If you have the possibility, then share the whole script with us.

Comment: @bobby: I have lots of python scripts on that machine. XMLRPC servers, FAPWS servers... They've been up for 2 years. Just saw the problem in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: @Christopher Mahan: Hard to track, especially for us. You can only verify the scripts and check if there were any recent changes, like new software, bash scripts etc. . Maybe the problem isn't directly related to the scripts, but rather to the way they get called/executed. One type can have funny side-effects.

Comment: @Bobby. True. I thought maybe someone had run into this and could point me in the right direction. There was an advisory on exim4 december 10 and the problem happened after that. I since apt-get remove --purge exim4 and it has not recurred, but I may have a compromised system, although top looks good and the system behaves well otherwise. Will rebuild asap anyway though.

Comment: @Christopher Mahan: That should have been typo in my last sentence...oh the irony...anyway, it could have been related to exim4, though I can't find anything that something like this has happened before. If you're adventurous you could reinstall it and see under which conditions it does return.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that some script running with root rights is moving its output into place.  So it does something like

```
... write data ... > /tmp/foo.$$.tmp
mv /tmp/foo.$$.tmp "$DEST"  # where "$DEST" is /dev/null -- ouch!
```

Comment: The only thing I have running are python scripts (which I wrote) so I know there's nothing like that in them, and a crontab job that looks like this: * * * * * /scripts/allmonitor.py 2>&1 > /dev/null

Comment: Are you sure?  Maybe something in one of the `/etc/cron.*/` directories?  Or some misconfigured startup script?  The redirect you posted shouldn't break /dev/null (though what you meant is correctly written `&> /dev/null` or `> /dev/null 2>&1` in that order).  The answer above is all that my crystal ball produces -- without more information it's impossible to remote-debug your problem.

Comment: I'll redo the > /dev/null 2>&1 part and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Once /dev/null has been clobbered once, any attempt to write to it will replace it with a file.  You have to recreate it using mknod.

Ok, I take that back - Debian stable uses udev, so you can recreate the stuff in /dev just by rebooting.  Back when men were men and Sun OS required to you recompile if you wanted more semaphores, a group of us spend some time trying to figure out why one part of our program was giving strange answers, until we realized that stdin was directed from /dev/null, and /dev/null had been replaced by a normal file, so every time it ran it got as input whatever had been output the last time somebody ran a program with the output redirected from /dev/null.

Comment: It will also be recreated when you reboot.

Comment: Does Debian stable use udev?  I thought it didn't.

Comment: Rebooting didn't restore /dev/null

Comment: So if /dev/null is a normal file instead of block special, what's in it?  Maybe the contents could tell you who is filling it?

Comment: @Christopher, if rebooting doesn't restore /dev/null, you probably do not have the /dev file system mounted properly. `mount` should give you a line like `none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)`.